# html() method to avoid writing

Tags: javascript, jquery

My query to the database is with AJAX , when you click on a link the html returns me a list from the database.
My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gnr a').on('click', function(){

     var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $.ajax({

           async:true,
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           url:"recibe.php", 
           data:"titulo="+title,
           beforeSend:inicioEnvio, 
           success:llegadaDatos,
           timeout:4000,
           error:problemas
         }); 
    });
});

function inicioEnvio()
{
$(".lista-usuario").html('<img src="loading.gif">');
}
function llegadaDatos(respuesta) {

   $(".lista-usuario").html(respuesta.datos1);
   $(".lista_usuario").html(respuesta.datos2);
   $("#art-list").html(respuesta.datos3);       
}
function problemas(){$(".lista-usuario").text('Problemas en el servidor.');}
```

I have a problem with function
html(respuesta.datos1) and html(respuesta.datos2) apparently there conflicto. Some times "data1" = null other times "data2" =null. Please how could correct that problem?

Comment: Have you tried with `async: false` ?

Comment: you need to utf8_encode() data1 and data2 in recibe.php

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function llegadaDatos(respuesta) {
   var usuario = resupesta.datos1 || respuesta.datos2;

   if (usuario) {
       $(".lista-usuario").html(usuario);
   }

   $("#art-list").html(respuesta.datos3);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $.ajax({

       async:false,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       url:"recibe.php", 
       data:"titulo="+title,
       beforeSend:inicioEnvio, 
       success:llegadaDatos,
       timeout:4000,
       error:problemas
     });
```

The "async:false" may solve your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the response as argument in you successhandler

```
$.ajax({

       async:true,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       url:"recibe.php", 
       data:"titulo="+title,
       beforeSend:inicioEnvio, 
       success:llegadaDatos(response), //<< !-important, your function expects an argument you didnt pass
       timeout:4000,
       error:problemas
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof respuesta.datos1 != undefined){
     $(".lista-usuario").html(respuesta.datos1);
}
```